# How to Connect Xamarin Mobile App Client to Azure Backend Database Server?

Tags: asp.net, azure, mobile, xamarin.android

I am trying to connect my mobile app developed using Xamarin MvvmCross to the Azure Mobile App backend database.

I have successfully done this before, until I created a new project and the new Azure backend server requires ZUMO-API-VERSION 2.0.0 to GET the data. I followed the exact same procedures on retrieving the data, starting from creating the data model, interface for azure and the data, as well as Azure database class. I also registered them in the *Setup.cs*.

I have put some data in the database. However, when I try to get the data using `var members = await memberDatabase.GetMembers();` the result is null. Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Here I attach some relevant codes:

*Project.Core/Models/Members.cs*

```
public class Members
{
    public Members() { }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string MemberSince { get; set; }
    public double CurrentBalance { get; set; }
}
```

*Project.Core/Interfaces/IDatabaseMembers.cs*

```
public interface IDatabaseMembers
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Members>> GetMembers();
}
```

*Project.Core/Interfaces/IAzureDatabase.cs*

```
public interface IAzureDatabase
{
    MobileServiceClient GetMobileServiceClient();
}
```

*Project.Core/Database/Members.cs*

```
public class AzureDatabaseMembers : IDatabaseMembers
{
    private MobileServiceClient azureDatabase;
    private IMobileServiceSyncTable<Members> azureSyncTable;
    public AzureDatabaseMembers()
    {
        azureDatabase = Mvx.Resolve<IAzureDatabase>().GetMobileServiceClient();
        azureSyncTable = azureDatabase.GetSyncTable<Members>();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Members>> GetMembers()
    {
        await SyncAsync(true);
        var members = await azureSyncTable.ToListAsync();
        return members;
    }

    private async Task SyncAsync(bool pullData = false)
    {
        try
        {
            await azureDatabase.SyncContext.PushAsync();

            if (pullData)
            {
                await azureSyncTable.PullAsync("Members", azureSyncTable.CreateQuery()); // query ID is used for incremental sync
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

*Project.Droid/Database/AzureDatabase.cs*

```
public class AzureDatabase : IAzureDatabase
{
    MobileServiceClient azureDatabase;

    public MobileServiceClient GetMobileServiceClient()
    {
        var platform = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(platform);
        CurrentPlatform.Init();

        azureDatabase = new MobileServiceClient("http://myweb.azurewebsites.net/");
        InitializeLocal();
        return azureDatabase;
    }

    private void InitializeLocal()
    {
        var sqliteFilename = "Local.db3";
        string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder
        var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path).Dispose();
        }
        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);
        store.DefineTable<Project.Core.Models.Members>();
        azureDatabase.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
    }
}
```

*Project.Droid/Setup.cs*

```
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    .
    .
    .
    protected override void InitializeFirstChance()
    {
        Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IAzureDatabase, AzureDatabase>();
        Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IDatabaseMembers, AzureDatabaseMembers>();
        base.InitializeFirstChance();
    }
}
```